Is it more efficient to optimize precision than covariance matrix?
This might be a silly question, but I want to make sure I'm not missing something.
Say that we want to fit a multivariate Gaussian distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$ to some data by maximizing the likelihood of the data. For some reason, we wish to maximize the likelihood of the data using gradient descent on the parameters $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ (e.g. we might want to impose a constraint or a penalization on $\mu$), constraining $\Sigma$ to be positive definite.
At each step of optimization we are evaluating the PDF of the Gaussian distribution on the data points, and thus we need to invert $\Sigma$. My question is, would it be more computationally efficient to optimize directly over the precision matrix $\Sigma^{-1}$? Is there some reason why we might prefer to optimize over $\Sigma$ and invert it at each step?

Short answer: probably not--it's a good idea.  But the precision matrix is not the only alternative parameterization worth considering.  The log eigenvalues of the precision, together with an orthogonal matrix, might work very well in some circumstances for instance.

Agree with @whuber and want to add: note that the log-likelihood relies not only on $\Sigma^{-1}$, but also on its determinant. So even if we parameterize by $\Sigma^{-1}$, we do avoid inversion, but not determinant calculation. And these are about as difficult as one another. This is why parameterizing with the log-eigenvalues as whuber suggested is nice: now we can easily do log-dets too. But This isn't a panacea, because per-iteration complexity isn't the only thing to consider: we also care about how many total iterations are necessary, and this is influenced in non-obvious ways.

@JohnMadden I couldn't find a reference for what you suggest. If you provide one, I'll try to answer my own question explaining the log-eigenvalue parametrization

@dherrera Ah, which part do you want a reference for? Computational complexity of determinant calculation? Impact of nonlinear transformation on gradient conditioning? Something else?
